# Connection of Avraham, Yitzchak, and Yaakov to birkat kohanim

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, birchas-kohanim

There is a man who davens in my minyan who loudly says "אברהם, יצחק, ויעקב" after birkat kohanim during chazarat hasha"tz. I have never seen anybody else do that, and I was wondering if there is a source or reason for it.

Comment: I have heard of a custom of saying "בזכות אברהם/יצחק/יעקב אבינו" after each line (each time mentioning one). Perhaps it's related.

Answer (score 2):

[Darash Av 184 - Bamidbar page 16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2985&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=) quotes the [Medrash Raba Breishis 43:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37457&st=&pgnum=112) which says that we were rewarded Birchas Kohanim due to the Avos. He says that is why some have the Minhag to say Bzchus Avraham Bzchus Yitzchak and Bzchus Yaakov.

> "מהיכן זכו ישראל לברכת כהנים? ר' יהודה אומר: מאברהם, דכתיב בפרשת לך לך
>   : כה יהיה זרעך, וכתיב כה תברכו את בני ישראל", ר' נחמיה אומר: מיצחק,
>   שנאמר: ואני והנער נלכה עד כה ונשתחווה ונשובה וגו' לפיכך אמר המקום: כה
>   תברכו את בני ישראל, ורבנן אמרי: מיעקב, שנאמר: כה תאמר לבית יעקב"

[Sefer Aile Hamitzvos - Mitzva 378](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37079&st=&pgnum=161) discussing Birchas Kohanim questions this Minhag. [Two pages later](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37079&st=&pgnum=163) he quotes the Baal Haturim that mentions that the first Pasuk in Birchas Kohanim is for Avraham. Second Pasuk is for Yitzchak. Third Pasuk is for Yaakov. He says this is a source of the Minhag.

Comment: Personally, I feel it's fine have the blessing in whoever's zechus it comes.